# Using the verb "line" for something round

Tags: verbs, suffixes

When we use the verb "line" in the following sense:

> The room was lined with bookshelves.
>
> We drove along a tree-lined highway.

Does "lined" necessarily have to denote things that run in a straight line? For instance, if you're walking in a round or twisting corridor where the walls are clearly not straight, can you still say something like:

> The arching corridor was lined with torches?
>
> The circular room was lined with bookshelves?

Comment: Your examples use lined as an adjective (not a verb), which really has little to do with lines.  https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/lined Also, https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/tree-lined

Comment: I just assumed since it's derived from the word "line," it has to describe something straight.

Comment: Lines don't have to be straight. We use the phrase "*straight* line" because it is necessary to specify. We can also specify a curved line or a wavy line or a jagged line and so forth.

Comment: I can see now that I may have taken leave of my common sense when I asked the question in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

> Does "lined" necessarily have to denote things that run in a straight line?

**No, not at all.**

Let's check the definition:

> Stand or be positioned at intervals along.
> *'a processional route lined by people waving flags'*
>
> <sub>-- [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/line)</sub>

Nothing here says that the intervals have to be in a straight line. Other dictionaries agree with this.

Comment: Many thanks! I'm writing a novel with lots of twisting passageways and I thought it'd be a pain to avoid the verb "lined" throughout.

Comment: How about 3D lining, @Rand al'Thor? Like, a box lined with paper, or a baking tin lined with pastry? Is it the same word? Just wondering 